# android Drawable - getConstantState.newDrawable() vs mutate()

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

In android I have read a few articles on how drawables share a constant state. So if you make a change to a drawable it affects all the same bitmaps. For example lets say you had a list of star drawables. changing the alpha on one will change all the star drawables alpha. but you can use mutate to get your own copy of a drawable with no shared state.
The article I was reading is [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html?m=1)

Now onto my question:

What is the difference between the following two calls in android:

```
Drawable clone = drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable();

// vs

Drawable clone = (Drawable) drawable.getDrawable().mutate();
```

For me they are both cloning a drawable as they both return a drawable that has no shared state. Am I missing something ?

Comment: You'll notice with `mutate` that `clone == drawable` is `true`.

Comment: i see, so mutate is the exact same drawable but without the shared state. and the drawable.getConstantState().newDrawable(); is actually a new drawable put in memory , correct ?

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: if you feel to make a official answer you can.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As @4castle pointed in comments `mutate()` method returns same instance of the drawable with copied constant drawable state. Docs says that

> A mutable drawable is guaranteed to not share its state with any other drawable

So it is safe to change a drawable without affecting drawables with the same state

Lets play with this drawable - a black shape

```
 <!-- shape.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

```
view1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape); // set black shape as a background
view1.getBackground().mutate().setTint(Color.CYAN); // change black to cyan
view2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape); // set black shape background to second view
```

The opposite method is `newDrawable()`. It creates a new drawable but with the same constant state. E.g. look at `BitmapDrawable.BitmapState`:

```
    @Override
    public Drawable newDrawable() {
        return new BitmapDrawable(this, null);
    }
```

Changes to new drawable will not affect current drawable, but will change a state:

```
view1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape); // set black shape as background
Drawable drawable = view1.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable();
drawable.setTint(Color.CYAN); // view still black
view1.setBackground(drawable); // now view is cyan
view2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape); // second view is cyan also
```

Comment: You sir, are correct, had the exact same problem and it solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Weird. I've got two drawables with the same resource next to each other. It seems .mutate() is automatically called since somewhere between Android9 and Android12 as setTint tints them sync in the older device, but distinct in the newer.. adding mutate fixed it, but I haven't found out why android 12 didn't need it before.