# How to pass parameters in Android drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

How to pass arguments in the android drawable.

How to acheive the below mentioned code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="{colorcode}" />
            <stroke android:width="1sp" android:color="{colorcode}" />
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

and then from XML file take this drawable passing values for parameters. Something like

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded,{colorCode}"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: You can not pass values like the aforementioned way from XML, as far as I know - would look forward to anyone else who may/can answer this if there's one. However, you can set values/pass arguments into android drawable programmatically, like changing solid color inside shape as asked in the question. Would that solve/help what you want to accomplish?

Comment: How we can pass arguments into android drawable programmatically ? I want to achieve both the thing 1. Change the radius and 2, Change the solid color.

Comment: Posted the answer. Please check and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Is there way that we can change radius with the help of style tag ? Like :                      
  ```<style name="RoundedCorner" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:shape">rectangle</item>
        <item name="android:radius">15dp</item>
    </style>```

Comment: Please check my answer, you'll get a good amount of radius properties (cornerRadius, cornerRadii etc), if you explicitly cast your drawable to ```GradientDrawable```. Edited the answer & added a couple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ShapeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable), [GradientDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable) & [ColorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable) are direct subclasses of [Drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable). You can explicitly cast your drawable to any of the aforementioned subclasses to invoke methods/property access like `setColor(int)`, `.paint` like the following:

```
val drawable: Drawable = (yourDrawable as StateListDrawable).getStateDrawable(0)
when (drawable) {
    is ShapeDrawable -> {
        (drawable as ShapeDrawable).paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorToSet)
    }
    is GradientDrawable -> {
        (drawable as GradientDrawable).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorToSet))
        (drawable as GradientDrawable).cornerRadius = 2.0F
    }
    is ColorDrawable -> {
        (drawable as ColorDrawable).color = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorToSet)
    }
}
```

Points to be noted:

You can use `mutate()` on this drawable because it returns the same instance of the drawable with the copied constant drawable state. The [mutate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable#mutate()) method doesn't share its state with any other drawable so it's pretty helpful if you want to keep the drawable as it is & then use it with different states in many places. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43800412/11040422) a great answer to how to use mutate on drawable & save states.

Additionally, as you mentioned in the comments, to change drawable radius too, use [cornerRadii](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable#getCornerRadii()) which as per the doc in the given embedded link, returns the radii for each of the 4 corners. For each corner, the array contains 2 values, `[X_radius, Y_radius]`. The corners are ordered `top-left`, `top-right`, `bottom-right`, `bottom-left`.

Comment: I am getting drawable as a StateListDrawable. So what is.the  solution now

Comment: Use ```getStateDrawable()``` & fetch that shape drawable. Then apply my answer. Please follow the link for its documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable#getStateDrawable(int)

Comment: Additionally, for supporting till API Level 21, use ```applyTheme()```. Link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable#applyTheme(android.content.res.Resources.Theme)

Comment: @AnupamSomani edited my answer to show how to get the drawable inside your StateListDrawable. Please check.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start) and BindingAdapter. I will show an example using Kotlin.

1. To enable data binding add to Your Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // only need when You use Kotlin

...
android {  
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
    }
    ...
}
```

2. Crete BindingAdapter (I am adding it to MainActivity.kt to simplify code):

```
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import com.myniprojects.teststackjava.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
                this, R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}

// Here is binding adapter. It takes 2 colors, background and stroke. If You want more customization add more parameters 
@BindingAdapter(value = ["colorStoke", "colorBack"], requireAll = true)
fun setBackground(textView: TextView, @ColorRes colorStoke: Int, @ColorRes colorBack: Int)
{
    val stroke = ContextCompat.getColor(textView.context, colorStoke)
    val back = ContextCompat.getColor(textView.context, colorBack)

    val gd = GradientDrawable()

    // setting background
    gd.colors = intArrayOf(
            back,
            back
    )

    // here change parameters as You want
    gd.gradientType = GradientDrawable.LINEAR_GRADIENT

    gd.shape = GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE
    gd.cornerRadius = 15f;
    
    // setting stroke width and color 
    gd.setStroke(5, stroke)

    textView.background = gd
}
```

To customize GradeintDrawable check [this docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable)

3. In Your MainActivity.xml do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="com.myniprojects.teststackjava.R" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtVTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView Text"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            app:colorBack="@{R.color.color_back}"
            app:colorStoke="@{R.color.color_stroke}"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

I am importing `R` to be able to pass resources. (Maybe there is another way without import but I couldn't pass color like `@{@color/name}` so I just import it). In Your `TextView` You have to call `app:colorBack` and `app:colorStoke` with colors that You want to set as stroke and back.

4. Of course in res/values/colors:

```
<color name="color_stroke">#B71C1C</color>
<color name="color_back">#33691E</color>
```

5. And final effect to show that everything works:

[image]

---

To generate `ActivityMainBinding` You first have to create a data binding layout. If You added Your dependency correctly to convert fast Your layout to data binding layout use: `Alt + Enter` ➡ `Convert to data binding layout`*

[image]

So Your layout should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

And now after rebuilding Your project You should get `ActivityMainBinding` class.

Comment: If I want to use in all the fragments I have to repeat 2 and 3 step every fragment ?

Comment: No You just create one BindingAdapter and then You can use it everywhere. So in second fragment You just create `TextView` and add `app:colorBack="@{R.color.some_color}"` and `app:colorStoke="@{R.color.another_color}"`. That's everything

Comment: class databinding.ActivityMainBinding not generate by itself anything I have to do for that

Comment: @AnupamSomani First option - You didn't add dependency correctly. After You do it, rebuild Your project. Second - Your main activity root element isn't layout. To do it just click alt + enter and You will see option "convert to data binding layout". After You do it You should see binding class

Comment: @AnupamSomani I have edited my answer to explain better how to generate `ActivityMainBinding` class